# Power BI measure to fill table rows

Tags: powerbi

I was wondering if its possible to create a measure in Power BI to fill rows with a certain word like "Yes" if another row is not blank.

The table should look something like this:

Item - Sold Number - Was anything sold

Bike - 100 - Yes

Car - 50- Yes

Truck - (blank) - (blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column(Flag) with the following:

```
Flag = IF(ISBLANK(your_table_name[Sold Number]),"Blank","Yes")
```